# Store images with unique filenames using hashing

Tags: java, servlets, hash

I'm looking for a solution for storing unique file names for a web application using Java Servlet.

What I need is to render profile images in a webpage, since I decided to store only file names in the database I have only to be sure they're unique in the image folder: to achieve that I was thinking to name images and save them with a string name composed by the couple:

```
<user_id>_<hash>.<file-type>
```

In this manner I think I would be pretty sure there will be no collisions, since user_ids are already unique.

1) Is this solution sound?

2) What algorithm should I pick for this purpose?

I'd like to use it properly so code snippets would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really simple approach would be to append `System.currentTimeMillis()` to the userid. If userid is unique then it should be pretty safe.

Comment: oh that's so much easier and simplifying, I've been too much "hashing enthusiast" I couldn't wait to use hashing for everything. Now I wish I had thought that at first. thanks for bringing me back to earth :)

Comment: You could encrypt or MD5 the result if you really wanted to (and you can get an MD5 method in Java)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`File#createTempFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) wherein you specify the prefix, suffix and folder. The generated filename is guaranteed to be unique.

```
File file = File.createTempFile("name-", ".ext", new File("/path/to/uploads"));
// ...
```

No, this file won't be auto-deleted on exit or something, it's just a part of temp file generation mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Why attach a hash or anything to it if its a 1 to 1 mapping? 1 user to 1 profile image, just use their id. If its a 1 to many, save the record in the database and get the id of that record and use that as the name. You might want to convert all your images to a particular image format too just to be consistent, so that wouldn't be stored in your database either.

BalusC tempfile method would work perfectly with this presented concept.